# Could our universe be destroyed within seconds?

Tags: cosmology, universe, multiverse

I'm not that deep in physics. But some days ago I read, there could be different coexisting universes, which could even share "space" (or what ever it is) where each of them could have absolutely different laws of physics.

Now when I'm thinking about the expanding of our universe is described by the speed of light what is an physical low by itself (isn't it?), Then I'm asking my self if there is another universe with physical  laws where the speed of light is an 'uncountable'(I don't know what power would suffice what I'm going to describe) times of ours, or even its expansion is mapped to something completely different.

Would there be something in our known laws of physics disproving or even supporting that there could be an universe expanding with such an power that if it 'hits' our universe, our universe would just blown out of existence within some seconds of our known timescale?

Comment: @CuriousOne: I just read about there is evidence of of an non-fatal collision our universe had which is observed by an in the article so called "scar" that shows an change in expansion on that point. So saying "There is actually no way to proof or disproof it, since we just can speculate" would be allready be an satisfying answer, not just comment

Comment: @CuriousOne: "I am not aware that we have any observations that would require any of these models as an explanation." please formulate your last 2 comments into an answer this is exactly what I wanted to hear. I didn't asked for proof or disproof. I asked about is proof or disproof even possible. And thats what you actually answered.

Comment: I'm afraid there's a lot of "woo" out there Zaibis. It sells magazines and more. Ignorant people lap it up, and there are others who are quite happy to fill a need. And of course promote themselves at the same time.

Comment: @JohnDuffield: We may be disagreeing a lot, but on this one I have to agree. The abuse of theoretical speculation to sell garbage science to layman who can't tell the difference has become an industry. Unfortunately even serious theoreticians are participating. I can see the financial pressure (theorists are being paid scraps), but it devalues science as a whole at a time when we can't afford it.

Comment: And thats why I didn't asked about an theorie itself, and more for an clarification, to identyfy this is just speculation or not. concluding thats why your comment was satisfying for answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Science is only concerned about things that have been observed, it can't speculate about things that have not been. Can one make models of the universe that look like high quality theoretical physics should and that would allow a rapid phase transition of the entire universe? Models like that are circulating in cosmology, e.g. colliding branes, vacuum instability etc. but lacking any evidence they are indeed just speculation.

There is nothing wrong with that, science thrives on intellectual speculation. The difficulty is turning it into "knowledge" by comparison with observations.

I am not aware that we have any astronomical observations or particle physics data that would require any of these models as an explanation. I can tell you my personal preference and I see the big bang itself as a possible candidate for such a rapid phase transition. But that's really my personal choice of physical mythology, it's not physics per se.

Comment: "Science is only concerned about things that have been observed, it can't speculate about things that have not been." Now that has to be the most ironic statement I have seen on PSE

Comment: @DirkBruere: It's simply the definition of science as a rational description of the natural world and method to its construction. Scientists can and do speculate about these things and that's among the best things in science. We can stand in our offices or next to our experiments with colleagues and talk about the fate of the universe in 1e100 years... and I love to do that. Science is not what scientists do all day, though. It's a very small subset of that, the distilled final result that gives a self-consistent picture of what is.

Comment: Well done for starting to answer questions again, CuriousOne. And I like this answer, so +1. @Dirk Bruere : me and CuriousOne had a little chat. Fingers crossed I can turn him into one of the good guys.

Comment: @JohnDuffield: The OP asked me to and indicated that (s)he got what (s)he was looking for. I think that's enough, even though I am not sure that it even begins to cover the topic for my taste. Thanks for the up-vote!

Comment: Science is **absolutely** concerned with things that have not (yet) been observed, but good theories are at least falsifiable. "if you point your telescope here you should see a previously unobserved planet" - the discovery of Pluto - is just one example. Maybe you and I are using "concerned with" in a different sense? Other than that I agree with you.

Comment: All points noted and agreed guys.